# DataContext connects to \\SQLEXPRESS while using PostgreSql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I develop an ASP.NET MVC application which uses a PostgreSql database. Model classes are in a different class library. For access to database I'm using Entity Framework + Npgsql.Entityframework.

As an example of settings for `app.config` I used this tutorial http://lvasquez.github.io/2014/11/24/EntityFramework-PostgreSql/.

My `app.config`:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" 
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
             requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="Npgsql" 
                  type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NpgsqlContext" 
         providerName="Npgsql" 
         connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=BaseId;Password=BasePass;Port=5432;Database=Base;" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" 
             invariant="Npgsql"
             support="FF" 
             description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql"
             type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

I removed all links to Entity Framework from basically project and it's `web.config`.

At the same time when I try to connect to database  context is connected through connection string

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NpgsqlContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Maybe someone already faced a similar problem?

Comment: If your project is a web project then these settings should be in the Web.config not app.config. It seems from your question you are posting an app.config. Can you confirm?

Comment: ojf, yes, it is. I want to allocate model classes from the main project and took out them in class library. In library is only app.config.

Comment: Are you running your code in the website? You cannot run a class library (dll) on its' own. It needs a host application. If the host application is a web.project then this config needs to be in the web.config of that site. The app.config file in your class library project is never used. If you are running your code in a test project or a console project then this config will need to be in the app.config of that project.

Comment: @ojf is right. You must change the `web.config` of the starter project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your code in the website then this config needs to be in the web.config of that site. You cannot run a class library (dll) on it's own. It needs a host application. The app.config file in your class library project is never used. If you are running your code in a test project or a console project then this config will need to be in the app.config of that project.

Comment: ojf, thank you! I added Entity Framework and Npgsql.Entityframework Nuget packages to main project and also all settings in web.config. Now database context has right connectionn string, but didn't see any records in datatable.

Comment: Also I have a question - in ASP.NET MVC generally impossible to achieve loose coupling between the parts of the application?